# Is it possible to create a Spring, Node Js project with Jhipster?

Tags: java, node.js, spring, jhipster

How can i use Jhipster to create a project with this structure :

-Spring Java back-end code with Maven

-JavaScript front-end with NodeJS, NPM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, JHipster currently only generates Angular frontends (both v1 and v2).  Angular 1 is JavaScript so that might fit what you are looking for.

You can also generate a backend only with `--skip-client`, and then code your own front-end.  In that case, how you set the frontend up is up to you.

Comment: When i use `--skip-client` , i get in installation second step : 
`(2/15) Which *Framework* would you like to use for the client? 
❯ AngularJS 1.x 
  [BETA] Angular 2.x` ; and there is no option to skip the select of the angular.

Comment: it worked with `yo jhipster:server` instead of `--skip-client` . Thanks